# Centrally align image in ImageView with scale type set to matrix

Tags: android, asynchronous, imageview, alignment

I'm building a Facebook like image viewer. Meaning I use a ViewFlipper containing some ImageViewers which load their images asynchronously. The scale type of the ImageViews is set to *matrix* as I want to pinch zoom the images once they are loaded. So far so good.

I would like to centrally align the images, any idea how to do this?

I tried

- to to change the scale type, this works but destroys my pinching behavior
- to move the image with a matrix but the image isn't loaded yet so the width is 0
- using an [OnLayoutChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html) but it's only added in API level 11
- playing with the [android:layout_gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) and [android:gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3agravity) params in the XML

Should I subclass ImageView and add a callback myself?

Comment: Have you tried setting the gravity to center in the layout file?

Comment: I tried setting "android:gravity" for the ImageView in the XML file but that didn't change a thing.

Comment: try 'android:layout_gravity' instead

Comment: Doesn't change a thing. I tried changing the *android:layout_width* as well but to no avail. Any other ideas?